# escaping in php

Tags: php

How do I escape for the following lines in php?

```
@[myvaule]"$array[$i]".docx
```

I tried doing this `` `@[m]"$array[$i]"`.docx ``, but I was getting the error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')'

I tried this:

```
@[rrent]".array[$i].".docx"
```

but I got an extra space after `array[$i]` like this `[myrstarray .docx`

If anyone can help that would be awesome.

Comment: You dont want for that line to show / be active at all? Please explain a bit more what you want :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a string out of it, Its better to put it inside a variable like this,

```
$filename = "[mytorrent]{$array[$i]}.docx";
```

Read more about [PHP string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).